# Why can't i do this iteration with json data?

Tags: json, iteration, type-mismatch

I tried this,

```
 var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        rows.push(['row' + i, i]);
    }

   data.addRows(rows);
```

This seems to work but when i do the same with json,

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'dbZipcode');
    data.addColumn('number', 'countusers');
var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < response.customerlist.length; i++) {
    rows.push(['Zipcode-' +  response.customerlist[i].dbZipcode, 
                               response.customerlist[i].countusers]);
}
   data.addRows(rows);
```

I gives me an error `Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type number in column index`. ANy suggestion.

and my json data looks like this,

```
 {
    "customerlist": [
        { "dbZipcode": "21313213",     "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "2313213",      "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "23324324",     "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "2342432",      "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "32424422343",  "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "324324324",    "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "324324324324", "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "3244324",      "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "3422344",      "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "342424324",    "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "3424324",      "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "435345",       "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "627028",       "countusers": "1" },
        { "dbZipcode": "641030",       "countusers": "2" },
        { "dbZipcode": "642582",       "countusers": "1" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your real code? Can you jsfiddle it?

Comment: @meder i ve tried http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/piechart.html#Example and i ve converted to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "1" in your JSON being seen as a String not a number?

Try

```
response.customerlist[i].countusers] - 0
```

so that it will be treated as an integer

Comment: thats why this forum and its users are rated highly in india.